# Ubuntu Packages not found even after updating sudo apt etc

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, locate

I'm rather new to Ubuntu but have been trying to install a number of packages through the bash from Windows. The problem for many of them is that it they are not found. I'm getting the error message:

E: Unable to locate package < package name >

I have tried all the readily available advice: updating through sudo apt update as well as upgrade. All repositories are available and I have checked the Ubuntu website for the exact packages so I am very certain that I have the right ones.

Since I also don't find any results with apt-cache search (except for already installed packages) and this is the case for several packages I am suspecting that the cache does not update properly but I can't figure out why or how to fix it. Any advice would be appreciated. (Using 20.04 (focal) and my internet connection does not seem problematic if that helps)

Comment: I'd suggest running `sudo apt update` and read the output ensuring there are no missing lines etc.  If new, you can add the output to your question so we can help you read it, or your sources; but we're limited mostly to what you provide. You can also use other commands too (eg. `apt-cache policy`, & more, but if you're not familiar with them those & better tools won't yet be known to you).

Comment: Another suggestion is to install Synaptic. That is a GUI package manager that just might help. Good luck :)

Comment: Lets have some apps names not just package name in the question. EDIT the question not as a comment.